# Upgrading from 3.0.5 to 3.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-3

Is it safe to upgrade from spring version 3.0.5 to 3.0.6 ?

Are there any issues I should watch out for ? Far as im aware there should be no issue as its such a minor upgrade in the version number, as opposed going from spring 1 to spring 3.

Why the down vote ?

Looking at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/changelog.txt there does'nt seem to be any mention of differences between 3.0.5 & 3.0.6. It jumps from 3.0.5 to 3.1 M1

Comment: I don't understand down-vote neither. I'm in process of upgrading form 3.0.5 to 3.1.0 and there are multiple issues including non backward compatible java interface changes, xml elements (primarily in spring security area) and changed defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had no problem with updating my project from 3.0.5 to 3.0.6

But you can use this query:

```
project = SPR AND issuetype = Bug AND affectedVersion = 11791 AND affectedVersion != 11636 ORDER BY priority DESC
```

To search for all [Spring Jira](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/IssueNavigator!executeAdvanced.jspa) Bugs that affect version 3.0.5 but not 3.0.5

But this list does not mean that the bug is added in 3.0.6, it just mean that maybe none checked it in 3.0.5